# WIFI blocked - Blacklisting blocks WIFI for dual boot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers

I dual boot Linux and Windows on my computer. I have recently gone from Linux Mint to Ubuntu. The WIFI isn't instantly compatible with Linux.
 What used to work from Linux Mint (which to my knowledge builds on Ubuntu) is to write **"blacklist acer_wmi"** to 
 **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist config**.

However, now that I run this command in Ubuntu it locks WIFI for all OS:es. That is, Ubuntu finds no wireless networks, **rfkill list** only lists Bluetooth, and, in Windows, the WIFI "option" is greyed out. Correcting the file mentioned above doesn't help. Actually, I have to format the hard drive and boot in legacy mode to have the computer find WIFI again.

I have no idea how to even begin troubleshooting this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

[EDIT]

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A4** gives the following

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev c3)
    DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak 2 7260 ac 2x2 + BT4 LE Combo
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[    7.682179] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.687544] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.764971] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    7.765045] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.765352] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.794846] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    7.798595] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.800784] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

**rfkill list** (if I blacklist acer, only the blutooth entry remains)

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**blacklist.conf**

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

**dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[    7.711214] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.716552] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.742759] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    7.742858] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.743103] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    7.743149] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.777035] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.793695] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

**rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Ubuntu commands can't affect Windows.

Comment: Edited the question!

@Pilot6 Seems counter intuitive. Especially since I can recreate the problem above by running said command.

Comment: Please replace it with `lspci -knn | grep Net -A4`. I see there must be a 3rd line. That's unusual.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It looks OK. What is the Ubuntu version? Please add `dmesg | grep iwl` and `rfkill list`.

Comment: The Ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: It looks like you added something wrong to `blacklist.conf`. Please post the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Comment: I do not see there `blacklist acer_wmi`.

Comment: No. I have since formatted my harddrive and reinstalled the OS:es. I have appended blacklist acer_wmi several times now without it helping.

Comment: Add it there or to a separate `blacklist-acer.conf` file.

Comment: So do it now. See my answer. Reboot after you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

Reboot after you do it.

That will create a file with this config. Alternatively you can add a line to `blacklist.conf` file.

You also may need to reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: Didn't work. Now there is no WIFI for the windows partition either.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf` and `dmesg | grep iwl` again.

Comment: cat just returns blacklist acer_wmi. The dmesg output is appended to the original question.

Comment: So it is still blocked by rfkill. Does `rfkill list` still show `acer-wireless`? If it does, please post `lsmod | grep acer`.

Comment: And also try to check if a hardware switch is there and it is on.

Comment: rfkill list does not show acer-wireless. It does show Wireless LAN, however

Comment: I do not know about a hardware switch. There is a "toggle WIFI" button. Pressing it does nothing.

Comment: Check the BIOS if the wireless is enabled there.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I find nothing about wireless in the Bios setup.

Comment: I am throwing in the towel now but thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: Then reset bios to defaults.